# How to name a variable that lists the values of a single property in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

I was wondering what's the clearest way to name a variable that lists the values of a single property in an array of objects.

Let's say I have an array of cats so that each cat has a list of favorite foods:

```
const cats = [
    {id: 34, name: 'Chonk', favoriteFoods: [2, 3, 4 12, 13]},
    {id: 66, name: 'Whiskers', favoriteFoods: [2, 4]},
    {id: 89, name: 'Melon', favoriteFoods: [1, 12, 13]},
    {id: 99, name: 'Jacob', favoriteFoods: [2]},
];
```

I need to assemble the favorite foods of all cats into one variable. Should I name that variable `catFavoriteFoods` or `catsFavoriteFoods`?

In my opinion `catFavoriteFoods` sounds more natural, but if someone else saw a variable called `catFavoriteFoods` they might think it refers to the favorite foods of a single cat, such as the list of Melon's favorites ([1, 12, 13]) in the earlier example.

With that in mind, would it be better to name the list that contains the favorite foods of all cats to `catFavoriteFoods`, `catsFavoriteFoods` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Since `favouriteFoods` lies within the object `cats`, I would name it something like `cats_FavouriteFoods`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of the preference and more than anything agreement between you and your teammates(if you are multiple to work on the project). However please refer to the MDN guidelines for variable naming.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/JavaScript#variable_naming

and no matter how you decide to name your variables stay consistent.